# Trying to drop Mac OS 9 disk image over sheepshaver on Sierra gives me error "Please drop either a file named 'Mac OS ROM'... "

Tags: macos, mac

I'm trying to install sheepshaver to run old mac games on my Macbook running Mac OS Sierra. I know I should download the Mac OS 9 image and name it "Mac OS ROM” and drop it over sheepshaver wrapper. I named it properly, dropped it on the wrapper, and I still get that message:

```
Please drop either a file named “Mac OS ROM” or a Mac OS installation disk image on me.

Do not drop any other kind of file.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need both: a [ROM file (1.9 MB)](http://www.redundantrobot.com/#/sheepshaver) and a locked [Mac OS CD installer image](http://macintosh463.rssing.com/browser.php?indx=25332140&item=32). It's funny to install Mac OS 9 in 2 minutes :-)

Comment: @klanomath my problem is that I can't mount (drag and drop on it didn't work) the ROM file onto sheepshaver. It throws the error. And the name of the ROM file is correct. I used ROM file from here:
http://www.redundantrobot.com/#/sheepshaver

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and realised that I was running the application from my Downloads folder, this violates the "app translocation" introduced in macOS sierra. You need to copy the application to another directory, e.g. the Applications directory and then copy the ROM file over.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, if it helps, but I also wasn't able to open the SheepShaver.app... until I downloaded the SheepShaverPrefs from here: 
http://www.emaculation.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=7360

I set it up, and then everything worked fine.

Comment: My issue was that message from the title of this question. I think I got to run the sheepshaver.